# Not getting the text from the success message div

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a div used for the success message. I want to get the text from that div. If i use element.gettext(); i am getting [] value, If I user element.getAttribute("value"); then I am getting [null] value. How to get the text? 
here is the success message div

`<div id="successMessageGrid" class="ng-scope" style="display: none;">
    <div class="alert alert-success media fade in ng-binding">
        Capability updated successfully.
        <button class="close" type="button" ngclick="RemoveSuccessMessage()"> 
        <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>`

If i submit the form then i will get this message . My code to get the data is

```
String Actual= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='successMessageGrid']/div")).getAttribute("value");
```

OR

```
String Actual= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='successMessageGrid']/div")).getText();
```

Comment: When you post a question, you need to tag it with the programming language you are using. It looks like Java? You need to post the actual code you are using. The code you posted won't compile because `.gettext()` is not a method... maybe you mean `.getText()`? My guess is that since it's a success message, you are getting the text before it's actually there. Add a wait and see if that helps.

Comment: I have tried with Wait and it works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below code:

`String Actual= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='successMessageGrid']/div")).getAttribute("innerHTML");`

Comment: I have tried this also, but there us button also in the div, so it is not working. I have tried with the wait and it works for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
/div[@id='successMessageGrid']//div
```

You can always use a site like this http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath to test your xpath expression first.

```js
function getElementByXpath(path) { return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue; }

console.log( getElementByXpath("//div[@id='successMessageGrid']//div").innerText );
```

```html
<div id="successMessageGrid" class="ng-scope" style="display: none;">
    <div class="alert alert-success media fade in ng-binding">
        Capability updated successfully.
        <button class="close" type="button" ngclick="RemoveSuccessMessage()"> 
        <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is not with the Xpath, I have tried that xpath for the different purpose, and it worked for me, But while getting the text only, I am facing the issue

Comment: see the answer again

Comment: There's no need to resort to JS for something like this. `.getText()` will work just fine.